# Compatibility issue in IE8 - ASP.NET MVC 3.0 intra application

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, iis-7.5

We have been developing ASP.NET MVC 3.0(Razor & HTML 5) application with IIS 7.5. The site should run on IE8.

The site content displays properly when the comaptibility mode is **OFF**. But, if it runs with compatibility mode on then the few elements goes outside horizontally.

As the company's IE policy, all the intranet application runs under the "Compatibility Mode" hence I can't change that part.

What should be possible solution? 
1. Is there any way when the application url gets renedered, I explicitly instruct browser to not run under compatibility mode (programmatically)?
2. Is there any ways in IIS 7.5 to enforce rendering targeting IE 8.0+?
3. Do I need to target to HTML 4.0 and convert all the fuzzy css/html targeting older html version?

I am seriously out of idea. It may possible the above direction points are also logic-less.

Please suggest somthing on this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set the X-UA-Compatible header. You can do in at least two ways:

Add the following to every page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Or you can tell IIS to send it with every response following [these instructions](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders) to set custom headers to every response.

For a list of values you can use `X-UA-Compatible` look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Add this `<meta>` tag inside `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This should force IE to use the most up-to-date rendering engine available.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to define it in the web.config?

Comment: Yes. Look [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started), "For IIS 7.0 and greater". Replace `chrome=1` with `IE=edge`.